# One 4TB hard drive or two 2TB in RAID 0 – which gives better performance?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, nas, synology

I’m looking into getting a new Synology NAS and looking at these two options for hard drives:

**2 bays:**

```
1 x 4TB  - file system (video, music, private cloud)
1 x 4TB  - daily backup
```

**4 bays:**

```
2 x 2TB  - RAID 0. (video, music, private cloud)
1 x 4 TB - daily backup
```

I could use the fourth bay with dedicated drive for backups of my PC and laptops.

I’m looking for the fastest read/write speed for my content. 
I’ve read few opinions saying that 2x2TB vs 1x4TB doesn’t make any difference but also some saying that two drives in RAID 0 performs better than just one on its own.

Comment: Dude i don't mean to be disrespectful but read the question before down voting. It says 2 x 2TB  - RAID 0.

Comment: Sorry for accusation :-). I corrected the sentence although I think it was quite clear that I didn't mean 1 disk in raid 0 just by looking at setup presented. I also don't consider it duplicated as the question you indicated  ask which is better, mine is specifically focused on performance.

Answer (score 1):

Two drives in RAID-0 will always (all else equal) have better *sequential* performance than a single drive, but not necessarily non-sequential.

Historically I would have said you're more likely to be limited by the NAS CPU/network performance than the hard drive but that's no longer true with recent units.

Historically I would also have said gigabit ethernet won't be maxed out by a single drive in normal use but again, that's not necessarily true with more recent drives.

One thing that is still true though is that having two drives in RAID-0 increases your risk of failure, as losing either disk would cause data on both disks to be inaccessible. But given you seem to have a reasonable backup plan in place that's much less of an issue.

I would personally say if the NAS (and your infrastructure) has 10GbE interfaces you'll benefit from RAID-0. If it only has 1GbE any benefits would be marginal and not worth the hassle. Being able to read off your drives at 200MB/sec isn't very helpful if it's being accessed through a 100MB/sec NIC.